# wpf resource dictionary suddenly not working fully

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a resource dictionary that has been working flawlessly up until I added a new theme file. Suddenly all the text box entries are not working.

Here is my problem
In the designer I get this (notice article #) 
[image: Designer] 
During runtime I get this
[image: Designer]

The resource dictionary worked flawlessly until I copied it to change colors, added an identical file with different colors and it all broke. The only thing that seems to be affected are SOME of the colors like in the image. I am not sure what is causing it, I checked all dynamic resources and they are all in tact like they were when it was working. Any ideas what might be causing it?

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                x:Class="Red"
                x:ClassModifier="public">
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="0Debugoverlay" Color="#9EA30A0A"/>
<Color x:Key="0Cutleft">#FFFF4444</Color>
<Color x:Key="0cutright">#C9FC0505</Color>
<Color x:Key="0selected">#FFFCA9A9</Color>
<Color x:Key="0BText">#FFF7A3A3</Color>
<Color x:Key="0Gradiant stop1">#FFBD2828</Color>
<Color x:Key="0Gradiant Stop2">#88BD2828</Color>
<Color x:Key="0Foregroundcolor">#FFD95F5F</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderDark">#FFCB4848</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderLight">#E5CC0000</Color>
<Color x:Key="TextBackground">#99000000</Color>
<Color x:Key="TextBackgroundLight">#99666666</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="0background" Color="Red"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="0foreground" Color="#FFE68181"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="0selection" Color="#FFBD2828"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="0bgopacityslider" EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF51919" Offset="0.45"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDA2323" Offset="0.9"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF800B0B" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<Color x:Key="0dropshadow">#FFBD2828</Color>
<Color x:Key="0dropshadows">#FFBD2828</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="0sliderforeground" Color="Black"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="0soundeffects" EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF0077E0" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF3A85B7" Offset="0.45"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF5BB0C2" Offset="0.9"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFBBF3FF" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="0speechvolume" EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF009900" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF38A338" Offset="0.45"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF38B738" Offset="0.9"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFC6FFC6" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="0speechrate" EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF383838" Offset="0.45"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF515151" Offset="0.9"/>
    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="0emulatebutton" Color="Black"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="0button" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF131313" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<RadialGradientBrush x:Key="0buttonline" Center="0.5,0.5" RadiusY="2">
    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.678"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#AD660000" Offset="1"/>
</RadialGradientBrush>
<Style x:Key="emulatebutton" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
</Style>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="0buttonGradiant" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF131313" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#AD660000" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="0buttonright" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF131313" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#AD660000" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

(only included part the file as it's very long but the affected parameter is "0foreground")

Comment: You don't show where you merge the dictionaries. Are you sure you did that correctly? Any conflicts between dictionaries?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that.  I merged them in app.xaml. Will update with the merged line. No conflicts that I can find.

Comment: <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary  Source="ResourceDictionaries/ResourceDictionary_ScrollBar.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Red/Red.xaml"/>
                <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Cyan.xaml"/>-->
               
                <ResourceDictionary x:Name="DefaultTheme" Source="Themes/custom.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>